# TypeScript Get IconName from string

Tags: angular, typescript, font-awesome

I'm working on Angular project, with typeScript.
I've added FontAwesome module.

Now I want to display FontAwesome Icon from string.

`

```
<fa-icon class="panel-heading__icon" [icon]="['fas', iconName]"></fa-icon>
```

`

When i put directly a good value of IconName, like that:
`

```
public iconName: IconName = 'coffee';
```

`

It works.

But, I need to pass a variable string and convert it to IconName.
`

```
this.iconName = this._model?.icon
```

`
I get : "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'IconName'.ts(2322)"

How fix it ?

Comment: you can try using `this.iconName = this._model?.icon as IconName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the typescript type checker is complaining because you are trying to use a string instead of an IconName. The IconName type from font-awesome is a type that allows different string literals but not any arbitrary string value.
You have two options to fix this problem:

Option 1:
Use the proper type for the icon attribute on the model type.
So for example if the type of the `_model` attribute is an interface this can look like this:

```
interface Model {
     ...
     icon: IconName
}
```

Option 2: If you can't change the model type you can tell the typescript compiler that you are sure that this icon property has the IconName type by using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions):

```
this.iconName = this._model?.icon as IconName.
```

Be aware that there is no runtime check that the icon attribute really hold a valid IconName.

Comment: Option 1 : move the problem to an other place.
I received by request the icon, so I need to tranform string to IconName.
Option 2: OK
I had already test that, my real problem was that I don't use the same version of fontawesome icon, I received name of font awesome icon version 6.2.0 instead of 5.15.0.